# How to stick a JDialog to a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, modality

it means when I click a button in my JFrame, a JDialog will be shown.I want to ban my JFrame, it won't be touch but still be shown on screen. 
I use command in my frame:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
               MyDialog md=new MyDialog(MyFrame.this);
               MyDialog.setVisible(true);                 
            }
        });
```

And in class MyDialog extends JDialog:

```
public MyDialog(MyGUI myGUI) {
    super(myGUI,true);}
```

Have something wrong in my code?
or Have another way to make it?
Please help me!!

Comment: Do you mean to make the dialog [modal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window)? Have a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html

Comment: I don't see anything wrong your code. You're setting your dialog modal by doing `super(myGUI,true);` already, so what is your question / what isn't working?

Comment: yes, my program still work but not except. My JFrame still can be touched when My JDialog is opened. I don't know the difference between two commands above:     new MyDialog(MyFrame.this) and new MyDialog(this). i wonder if itself is reason?

Answer (score 2):

Add this before `MyDialog.setVisible(true);`:

```
MyDialog.setModal(true);
```

**EDIT**:
This has the same effect as the `JDialog(Frame owner, boolean modal)` constructor that you are already using. Are you sure you aren't already getting a modal dialog?

Comment: yes,JDialog and JFrame still work specially. I still can create the different JDialog when I click the button in JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

I found my case. I used to some setting for JDialog, and two of them is :

```
Container con= getContentPane();
con.add(p);
```

sorry everybody for my pool JAVA. I'm a beginning and I'm trying to increase my knowlegde. Thank you very much!